# How to run a C# console application with the console hidden

Tags: c#, console-application

Is there a way to hide the console window when executing a console application?

I am currently using a Windows Forms application to start a console process, but I don't want the console window to be displayed while the task is running.

Comment: try running the console application from scheduled task.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show/Hide the console window of a C# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application)

Answer (score 174, accepted):

If you are using the `ProcessStartInfo` class you can set the window style to hidden - in the case of console (not GUI) applications, you have to set CreateNoWindow to `true`:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo start =
      new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
start.FileName = dir + @"\Myprocesstostart.exe";
start.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //Hides GUI
start.CreateNoWindow = true; //Hides console
```

Comment: Just what I was going to post :)

Comment: Holy crap - someone faster than Jon! =)

Comment: I had to throttle his internet connection to beat him ;)

Comment: It did not work for invoking a command line tool. Used yourprocess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow=true; instead, see below.

Comment: Doesn't hide the console window, StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true is required.

Comment: @ErikForbes Happened to me once aswell. I was faster than Jon once. I have that to say :) Happened to me here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710975/how-to-use-partial-method-in-c-sharp-to-extend-existing-implemetation/32711062#32711062

Comment: This will not hide a **console** application's console window. The [WindowStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle.aspx) property applies to GUI applications only. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/848343/1889329), on the other hand, does hide the console window. 120 upvotes (with 2 downvotes) for an answer that doesn't even work? The voting system is in a pathetic state.

Answer (score 234):

If you wrote the console application you can make it hidden by default.

Create a new console app then then change the "Output Type" type to "Windows Application" (done in the project properties)

Comment: I was trying to hide my own console, not call something else and then hide it (like the accepted answer assumes) - so this was the best one for me. thanks!

Comment: The accepted answer assumes that because it's stated in the question.

Comment: simplest way..really liked it..we certainly do not want to show the window beacuse it  is going to launch another process from it for me..

Comment: This one gets around issues with ProcessStartInfo where you specify user credentials and that user happens to be logged in or current user. In that situation the CreateNoWindow property is ignored so you always get a console window. By setting the console app to Windows Application but without a window then you get no window.

Comment: This one makes a different result to what I am looking for. I want the console window to be minimized but still be there for me to maximize it. With this approach there is no window in the first place.

Comment: Note, in VS 2017, it's labeled Windows Forms Application under Application Type.

Comment: Solutions like this really make you scratch your head as to what Microsoft was thinking... Not intuitive at all...

Answer (score 69):

If you are using Process Class then you can write

```
yourprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
yourprocess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

before `yourprocess.start();` and process will be hidden

Comment: Good luck if you have to stop that process early.  Process.Kill terminates abruptly.  Process.CloseMainWindow fails.  GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent fails to send ctrl+c or ctrl+break to the process. WM_CLOSE to all thread windows in the process fails.  There seems to be no way to cleanly end a process started with those two parameter values.  See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139571/how-to-cleanly-shut-down-a-console-app-started-with-process-start

Comment: Thanks tons this was the simplest.  Also if you own (or dept) the code for the console I found this mutex example to be the easiest for clean shutdown.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31586184/1877412

Comment: @Triynko: You cannot cleanly terminate any process, unless that process actively coöperates. This is not a matter of flags or anything else. There's just nothing in the OS that could trigger a clean shutdown. The common solution here is to use a waitable kernel object, that's signaled in the controlling process, when the slave process should terminate. The slave process needs to actively monitor the state of this waitable object, and initiate clean shutdown once it's signaled.

Comment: The child process can also use the parent process as a signal for shutdown (if the child process should not outlive the parent. Pass in the parent PID, use `Process.GetProcessById(pid).WaitForExit(...)` to wait or poll. Just one option.

Answer (score 50):

Simple answer is that: Go to your console app's properties(project's properties).In the "Application" tab, just change the "Output type" to "Windows Application". That's all.

Comment: Bullseye. This is the same as creating a Windows application that doesn't call any forms.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  None of your other bandaid approaches.  This is the actual RIGHT answer.  You want your application to never open a console in the first place.  Also, you want to be able to open a form at any time.  So you just call the form when you want.  i.e. our form is called when the user right clicks on the system tray icon and selects preferences.
THIS IS THE RIGHT ANSWER!!!

Answer (score 22):

You can use the [FreeConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to detach the console from the process :

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool FreeConsole();
```

(of course this is applicable only if you have access to the console application's source code)

Comment: I wanted to not show the console. While `FreeConsole` does what its name says, it doesn't prevent Windows from showing the console before it is called.

Comment: Then compile the project as a Windows Application, not a Console Application

Comment: For the record, this is exactly what *I* needed, thanks. It also is _exactly_ what the title asks for :) So in the interest of other google voyagers, +1

Comment: In addition `[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] static extern bool AllocConsole();` allows you to easily run _with_ a console from a standard Win32 application

Comment: Works for my .NET Core 2.2 app - if anyone is looking for this specifically.

Answer (score 7):

If you're interested in the output, you can use this function:

```
private static string ExecCommand(string filename, string arguments)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(filename);
    psi.Arguments = arguments;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo = psi;

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => { output.AppendLine(e.Data); };
    process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => { output.AppendLine(e.Data); };

    // run the process
    process.Start();

    // start reading output to events
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    // wait for process to exit
    process.WaitForExit();

    if (process.ExitCode != 0)
        throw new Exception("Command " + psi.FileName + " returned exit code " + process.ExitCode);

    return output.ToString();
}
```

It runs the given command line program, waits for it to finish and returns the output as string.

Answer (score 4):

If you're creating a program that doesn't require user input you could always just create it as a service. A service won't show any kind of UI.

Comment: But if all you want to do is run the process until it exits, e.g. by calling it from the Task Scheduler, then a service is inconvenient as it continues to exist. In some situations changing the Output Type to Windows Application versus the alternative ProcessWindowStyle as hidden is very convenient.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your class to import the DLL file:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow); 

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] 
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

const int SW_HIDE = 0;
const int SW_SHOW = 5;
```

And then if you want to hide it use this command:

```cs
 var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
 ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);
```

And if you want to show the console:

```cs
var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
        const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        const int SW_SHOW = 5;

Answer (score 2):

I've got a general solution to share:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WhateverNamepaceYouAreUsing
{
    class Magician
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        const int HIDE = 0;
        const int SHOW = 5;

        public static void DisappearConsole()
        {
            ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), HIDE);
        }
    }
}
```

Just include this class in your project, and call `Magician.DisappearConsole();`.

A console will flash when you start the program by clicking on it. When executing from the command prompt, the command prompt disappears very shortly after execution.

I do this for a Discord Bot that runs forever in the background of my computer as an invisible process. It was easier than getting TopShelf to work for me. A couple TopShelf tutorials failed me before I wrote this with some help from code I found elsewhere. ;P

I also tried simply changing the settings in Visual Studio > Project > Properties > Application to launch as a Windows Application instead of a Console Application, and something about my project prevented this from hiding my console - perhaps because DSharpPlus demands to launch a console on startup. I don't know. Whatever the reason, this class allows me to easily kill the console after it pops up.

Hope this Magician helps somebody. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm not answering exactly what you want, but I am wondering if you're asking the right question.

Why don't you use either:

1. windows service
2. create a new thread and run your process on that

Those sound like better options if all you want is to run a process.

Comment: There are plenty of scenarios where launching a utility console application is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: In my case a separate process is necessary because of the client/server model that the software I am working on uses.

Comment: It doesn't always solve the problem to create a new thread. There are times when you just don't want the annoying window in the background. Also, what if you have a process.start in a loop, then you won't get any work done as console windows pop up in your face.

Comment: I launch windowless utility console apps from the Task Scheduler. No need for service, and no parent process from which to fork a thread. These apps write to the EventLog if additional output needed.

Answer (score 1):

Although as other answers here have said you can change the "Output type" to "Windows Application", please be aware that this will mean that you cannot use `Console.In` as it will become a NullStreamReader.

`Console.Out` and `Console.Error` seem to still work fine however.

Comment: Are you serious? Why would anyone use `Console.In` when there is no console to input something? Where should anything come from that can be accessed via `Console.In`? This doesn't make any sense at all.

In other words: It is totally obvious and logical that `Console.In` is a `NullStreamReader` in this case.

Comment: @RobertS. A pipe maybe. I.e. the output of another program. That was my use case when I discovered this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Adam Markowitz's answer above, following worked for me:

```
process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/k \"" + CmdFilePath + "\"");
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
//process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
//process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
ProcessStartInfo psi= new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
......

psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
```