# How do I create a C# program without a GUI?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I know that you can create a Windows Forms application and set it to be invisible. And if I create a console application (the console window will open- and I have no use for the console), how do I create a simple application that has no GUI at all?

Comment: You can hide the console window as well with an API call. Where are you runnng this from, another aplication, the desktop. Is it a service, or just a one off do something and quit?

Comment: Write a console mode app and just change the Output type setting to "Windows application"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Create a windows application, remove the Form1.cs file, edit the Program.cs file to remove the lines

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Put your own code instead, and you're done.

Answer (score 4):

You could create it as a [windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836427/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-console-application-with-the-console-hidden) also has some options for running an existing console application with no console window, so you could write a console application, then write a console application which launches that with its window hidden and then closes.