# Send a string to IE and IE execute the string but not have IE appears or the Console screen appear

Tags: c#

I don't know if it is possible to do this in Windows Console Application (C#) but I really need something like this for my project.

I would like to send a string (or URL link) to the IE and have IE execute that string. However, since this string is static; what it does is just turn a machine ON and OFF via internet. So, in this case I have no interest in seeing the IE to popup/display nor the black screen console to appears when the application got executed.

I know in Console Application C# we can do something like this

```
        Process.Start("iexplore.exe", @"http://myserver.com");
```

However, when I run the above line, the IE popup and so does the black screen console.

Is there a way to not have IE popup and the screen console to not popup, too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are going about this the wrong way. IE is merely a portal to web requests. Just make the web request call directly. using something like the new Web API or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)

As to making the console not pop up, maybe you should be creating a Windows Service instead of a console application? We would need more details on the end user. If this is more of an automated action, then a service would work. If it is something the user clicks on, then why is displaying the console a bad thing? Typically, when you click on something you expect some sort of visual representation. But, [here is a SO that answers this question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836427/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-console-application-with-the-console-hidden)

Answer (score 0):

Try `ProcessStartInfo`. This will hide the console app, but I'm not positive about it hiding IE.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("iexplore.exe", @"http://myserver.com");
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: hi
I am currently using http request, now, this does pop of the console screen. I really want to hide this screen.

Comment: // prepare the web page we will be asking for
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("myserver.com");
        // execute the request
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) 
            request.GetResponse();