# Update early bound helper file programmatically

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

is there a way to programmatically update helper file created primarily with CrmSvcUtil.exe in CRM 2011?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CrmSvcUtil is basically a console application you should be able to start it programmatically with a C# application.

[How to run a C# console application with the console hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836427/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-console-application-with-the-console-hidden)

Answer (score 0):

You could run a batch file doing it for you but I'm guessing that you'd like it to be run upon you creating/updating an entity. I don't think there's a way to make CRM detect such a change and execute a file on your machine. My answer is no, but it'd be nice if someone knew of a way and put me corrected.

Comment: Well as its a development environment you could have a plugin that runs svcutil from a shared folder on your machine (or on the server itself).

Comment: Good point: +1. My boss made me do on-line version from the very start. It's in my bones - "if you can't do it on-line, you shouldn't do it at all".   :D