# c# enable console without modify output type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I'm building a windows application, but I need also the features of the console.

If I change the output type from *Windows Aapplication* to *Console Application* it works fine, but it shows always the console.

It's possible enabling the console by code only in certain situations?

thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472282/show-console-in-windows-application

Comment: thanks! it works!        `AllocConsole();

                    Console.WriteLine(@"hello. It looks like you double clicked me to start
                   AND you want console mode.  Here's a new console.");
                    Console.WriteLine("press any key to continue ...");
                    Console.ReadLine();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this can  be of any help:

[How to run a C# console application with the console hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836427/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-console-application-with-the-console-hidden)

The person asking the question was running a WinForms app where he executed other things through a console application without showing it. Seems similar to your situation. Hope this helps! :)