# Ghostscript suppress output windows when called by command line

Tags: c#, command-line, ghostscript

This is my scenario:

I'm converting PDF files to PNG images calling Ghostscript by C#. This is the argument string I use:

```
-dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dFirstPage=1 -q -r300   -sDEVICE=png256 -sOutputFile=...
```

But, in this way, when I call Ghostscript it shows a window where (before I've added `-q`) there were output messages.

I've tried adding `-dNODISPLAY` after `-r300`. But in this way Ghostscript doesn't work and doesn't create images.

**Question:**
In which way can I suppress the output window?

Comment: I suggest looking at https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET

Comment: or https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/

Comment: @kjtl thank you for the answer but I need to use classic ghostscript calling it like command line

Comment: Can you please post complete line with exe name? There are 2 exe files, one ends with 'c'. The 'c' in the name is to indicate it's for console only. Try to call gswin32c.exe instead gswin32.exe.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to run Win32/Win64 Ghostscript on the commandline without having it popping up a separate window (to display its `<stdout>` and `<stderr>` messages and allow you for `<stdin>` input typing), then use these binaries (depending on your version of your locally installed Ghostscript):

- `gswin32c.exe` (note the added `c` for `command`/`console`)
- `gswin64c.exe` (note the added `c` for `command`/`console`)

Do not use `gswin32.exe` or `gswin64.exe`! These are the versions which bring along their own popup windows...

Comment: thank you, I was using gswin32.exe instead of gswin32c.exe. For others that have same problem, see also the nld answer at this question to hide console: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836427/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-console-application-with-the-console-hidden

Comment: Can you post an example usage of how it is being called in c# ?

gswin32.exe with parameters it works but when I switch gswin32.exe to gswin32c.exe   
                    at process.WaitForExit(); line it gets into infinite loops

Comment: I am still seeing a console window popup when using the c version...

Comment: I'm seeing a console window as well. It just no longer pops up in it's own "ghostscript" console window

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential windows that can pop up when you're running gs:

- On Windows, you might get a terminal window to popup. ⇐ This isn't specific to GhostScript.
- On all systems, you might get a render window to popup.

In case the window that you want to suppress is the render window, for example, because you want to use PostScript as a programming language, you might want to change the device to `nullpage` using the `-sDEVICE=nullpage` option:

File `hello.ps`

```
(%stdout)(w)file (Hello, world!\n) writestring
```

Command to run this file, without a window popping up using the `nullpage` with `-sDEVICE=nullpage`, and also suppressing GhostScript's banner message with `-q`:

```bash
gs -q -sDEVICE=nullpage -- hello.ps
```