# Ghostscript - Silent no popup printing

Tags: pdf, printing, ghostscript

I currently am coding a PDF printer for work that is unattended on a server. Basically, we have a PDF file already created... and we are telling ghostscript to Print the document to the printer passed in.

However, the Ghostscript DLL always pops up a dialog showing what it's doing... such as ... Printing page 1... etc....

[Screenshot of popup..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chtdx.png)

I want to have complete silent printing. I've tried -dQUIET ... but that has no affect.

```
            Dim switches As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
            With switches
                .Add("-dPrinted")
                .Add("-dBATCH")
                .Add("-dNOPAUSE")
                .Add("-dNOPROMPT")
                .Add("-dNOPAGEPROMPT")
                .Add("-dNOSAFER")
                .Add("-dNumCopies=1")
                .Add("-sDEVICE=mswinpr2")
                .Add("-sOutputFile=%printer%" + strPrinterName)
                If Me.Orientation = PrinterOrientation.vbPRORLandscape Then
                    .Add("-c")
                    .Add("<</Orientation 3>> setpagedevice")
                End If
                .Add("-f")
                .Add(fileName)
            End With
```

Is there another switch that I'm missing? Or is it not possible to have 0 popup showing the status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/Devices.htm#Win) describes (Section 10.1) the `-dNoCancel` switch:

> Hides the progress dialog, which shows the percent of the document
>   page already processed and also provides a cancel button. This option
>   is useful if GS is intended to print pages in the background, without
>   any user intervention.

Comment: What version is that in? 9.23 doesn't show that option under "How to use..." However, I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: That worked! Case sensitive. Most of the other commands are capitalized. I did your version and it worked. Thank you!!

Comment: This is the page I was referring too. 
  https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/Use.htm

Comment: All the Ghostscript command line switches are case-sensitive (because PostScript is case sensitive). I see my link got messed up and used the local file system, should have been: https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/Devices.htm#Win which is the page documenting each specific device, in this case the Windows printer device.

Comment: Bam! Thanks! I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows you want to ensure that you are running

gswin32**c**.exe (note the added c for command/console)

OR

gswin64**c**.exe (note the added c for command/console)

rather than gswin64 or gswin32.

See [Ghostscript suppress output windows when called by command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340019/ghostscript-suppress-output-windows-when-called-by-command-line) for details.