# Is it possible to flash the command prompt window

Tags: c#, cmd

After searching extensively, I can only find an API to move the window. This is not what I want.

I want to either temporarily hide then show the window or if you know of an existing method that can be used to flash the window, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: same as the API to move the window, which is probably SetWindowPos, there is also another Win32 API like ShowWindow which you can use to hide/show any window once you know the handle of it. To find the handle of any window you can use the API FindWindow in case in conjunction with EnumWindows if needed....

Comment: David's comment should help you.  Btw why do you need it? What is the benefit of flashing the window ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I guess she wants to run the application in silent but doesn't know how to phrase it. Anyway http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836427/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-console-application-with-the-console-hidden does this help?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I have a made a little countdown timer and I would like it to flash when I have less than 5 minutes remaining on the clock :)