# Running an EXE with parameters after installation of the files using WIX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, exe, bootstrapper, burn

I have this installer through which I'm installing Mosquitto as a re-requisite for my system. But after installation I need to run the EXE passing two parameters. The command to run would be "mosquitto -v -c mosquitto.conf". I tried to do this using the following command but nothing happens.

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[mosquitto.exe] -v -c mosquitto.conf" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="RunMosquitto" Before="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

what is the right way to do this? Also I need to stop this EXE during uninstallation. How can I do that as well? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, according to [this WiX mailing list archive](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Passing-command-line-arguments-to-an-app-launched-after-setup-td1366362.html).

Bob Arnson, one of the WiX developers, said the following:

> WixShellExecTarget must be only the path of the executable/document. 
>   There's no support to add arguments. For that, use a "normal" exe custom 
>   action instead of WixShellExec.

Comment: If I use the normal exe custom action it opens a console. Isn't there a way to run the thing in background?

Comment: I think you'd probably have to write a custom action that called into code that did that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836427/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-console-application-with-the-console-hidden