# Extracting the first page of multiple PDFs & saving them as Image

Tags: c#, image, pdf

I have about 400 ebooks, all in PDF format, and my task is to extract the cover from every one of them (which is the first page of every PDF) and export them all as separate image (PNG or JPEG) files

So I will end up with 400 ebooks and 400 images of their covers.

I have Windows

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: OK - So what have you written so far?  This is discussed in a lot of places already.  What part of your attempt is not working?

Answer (score 2):

Use ghostscript to render tiff or jpg from the pdf. You have fine grained control over the result.

If this is a commercial application, you need a commercial license. If you use the application commercially, but inside your organisation, you are allowed to use the GPLed version of ghostscript.

Ghostscript can be found here. The PDF interpreter in many opensource packages relies on the gs PDF interpreter. Imagemagick for example, requires ghostscript libraries.

Download GS here: http://ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html

Use C# `Process` class to execute Ghostscript, there is a SO topic on this here [How to run a C# console application with the console hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836427/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-console-application-with-the-console-hidden)

The commandline for tiff will be:

```
D:\gs\gs9.20>bin\gswin64c.exe -sOutputFile=d:\some%02d.tiff -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiff24nc -sCompression=lzw -r150 -sPageList=1 d:\PDFReference.pdf
```

This will create one `some01.tiff` file on `d:\` in 150dpi resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The following thread is suitable for your request. converting pdf file to an jpeg image

One solution is to use a third party library. ImageMagick is a very popular, freely available too. You can get a .NET wrapper for it here. The original ImageMagick download page is here.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/pdftoimages.aspx Convert PDF pages to image files using the Solid Framework
http://www.print-driver.com/howto/convert_pdf_to_jpeg.html Universal Document Converter
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-ways-to-convert-a-pdf-file-to-a-jpg-image/ 6 Ways To Convert A PDF To A JPG Image
And you also can take a look at this thread: how to open a page from a pdf file in pictureBox in C#

If you use this process to convert a PDF to tiff, you can use this class to retrieve the bitmap from tiff.